# What other Imperial targets did Rahm Kota attack in the months leading up to Force Unleashed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In Star Wars: The Force Unleashed, Starkillers first target is General Rahm Kota, a Jedi gone guerilla leader that has been attacking imperial targets in an attempt to draw Vader out.

As you encounter Kota, he utters the following:

> "...a boy? Months of attacking Imperial targets and Vader sends a boy to fight me?"
>
> ― Rahm Kota

### Is it known what other military targets, other than the TIE Fighter factory, Kota has targeted?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rahm_Kota#cite_note-TFUcg-6) in *The Force Unleashed Campaign Guide* he attacked a factory that Darth Vader had recently visited? While also commandeering Vader's personal shuttle.

> Kota and his militia remained hidden, emerging only to strike at Imperial targets in well-executed and carefully planned raids.
>
> [...]
>
> While conducting his rebellion, Kota took an intense interest in Darth Vader himself, attacking targets that appeared to have some level of importance to the Dark Lord, such as assaulting a factory that he had recently visited and stealing a shuttle that Vader had used as a personal transport.

Comment: I've formatted the link so it's clickable (it needed `http://` at the front) and so it reads better in the post, this can be done with the markdown `[link text](link)`. I've also edited in the relevant information from the link in case the link dies.